# Correct use of express in Node js

Tags: node.js, http, express

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.listen(10000);

function function_a(inp)
{
    var tmp_var = inp;
    console.log(tmp_var) 
    //10 - the first time
    //20 - the second time

    app.get('/pageno1', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('...');
        //..
        console.log(tmp_var) //10 - on both calls
        //..
    });
}

function start(/* .. */)
{
    //...
    function_a(10);
    function_a(20);
}
```

Suppose that I have two functions that simplified look something like the above. My issue is that the `tmp_var` holds the same value on both calls inside the `app.get('/pageno1')` even though I pass a different value.

Two points I would like to bring your attention to;

a) I dont use `next();` (I am not sure if thats the issue),

b) I dont have a 'default' page (`app.get('/', ...)`) because I didnt need it (kinda weird, but thats my case.) I dont mind adding one, if thats the issue.

**EDIT**:

What is the expected end result: Get the URL parameters passed onto a URL and (eg: example.com/route?=<...>) and redirect the user to a page. After that is done in my code, in another function, use a stored variable and do some other things, using the parameters gotten from the URL and the stored variable. Wait for next GET request.

What I tried:

```
app.get('/pageno1', (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('https://..');
    //when that is done, move to another function
    //here comes the issue (that other function needs the stored variable)
    //and although its not needed inside `app.get` I need to pass it to the
    //function after thats done.
    function_A(param, req.query);
});

function_A(inp1, inp2)
{
    //do some things
}
```

If that can be done using native HTTPS module, I don't mind not using express.
Lastly in case its not clear, I want to pass the local variable in the other function (function_A). So not necessarily inside the /pageno1 request. But, AFTER the pageno1 request is done, I need both the local variable and the req from the request to call the function_A.

If you need better explanation in anything, feel free to ask!

Comment: `20` would never be reached because it's on the same route as `10`, which was defined first, and doesn't call `next`. If it did call next, an error would be thrown due to `10` sending a response (the redirect)

Comment: Oh, okay that clears things a bit. So if I cant use next due to the redirect how can I 'end' that route, so I can re-return?

Comment: You can call next, or you can redirect. doing both makes no sense.

Comment: You can't get to `20` without calling next or having it on a separate route all together.

Comment: So I cant redirect and get to 20 at the same time? I dont need next, thats why I didnt use it, (since as you said I redirect)

Comment: The bigger question here is why are you defining two route handlers for `/pageno1`?  You should have only one route handler for that.  It really makes no sense to have two handlers for the same route designed to do different things.  Please back up to the root cause that led you to even try to do this.  Then, we can talk about the right way to solve your problem.  As it is now, all we can do is explain why a wrong design doesn't work, but until you describe what you're really trying to accomplish, we can't help you get to the right design.

Comment: If both 10 and 20 redirect (or respond), you don't want both running. If neither redirect, they can both run, no problem.

Comment: A given route handler does one of two things:  1) Send a response (`res.redirect()` is a type of response) or 2) call `next()` to let some other handler later in the chain send a response.  You can't do both.  You can't set things up for two route handlers to both send responses (that will be an error).

Comment: Okay, got it, I might have misunderstood the use of routes so let me explain a bit more what am trying to do. 'pageno1' (lets say 404) gets called, I get some data using req and I redirect the user to another page (eg: homepage). Each time I want to pass a different number as a parameter because I want to show a different image, hence the tmp_var. I noticed I was doing something wrong when the same tmo_var was getting passed.

Comment: I dont know if there was a simpler way (eg: using native https) but all I wanted to do was just that. After I get to pageno1, redirect the user somewhere else, and depending the one variable passed do something. At the end 'clear' everything up for the next user.

Comment: @jfriend00 So based on the upon explanation, how do you think I should do it

Comment: Still don't understand what you're trying to do.  When you say pass a different number as a parameter, where does the number come from and how do you expect it to get passed?  The user makes a request to an URL.  Is there a number in the URL?  There's no passing at that point.  The user makes a request.  You look at the URL and decide what type of response to send.

Comment: No thats my whole issue. There is no number in the URL, I have to pass it from my code.

Comment: I expect it to be passed like in my example above, from a variable in the code. Let me re-phrase my question since I don't necessarily need express. How can I listen to a specific port, use HTTPS GET, check for only two URL and then get some info from the URL. Lastly pass a local variable from my code into the function (needed because its not passed from the URL and I have to create it in my code) and move on.

Comment: Pass it from your server code makes no sense.  A route handler is a fixed thing.  It's the same route handler no matter which client requests it now or a year from now.  If you want to do something different from one request to the next, then put the code INSIDE the route handler to determine what to do and when, but probably you just have a flawed design if you're trying to do something completely different the second time a route is called.  It sounds to me like you don't really understand the whole request/response logic of http or what a good REST URL design is.

Comment: Also, what does "get info from URL" mean?  You don't pass a local variable into a request handler.  The request comes from the client, not from your code.  That's just not how web servers work.

Comment: If you want to rewrite your question to make it clear, then forget about your code for a second and just describe what you want to happen.  Client requests URL `http://myserver.com/route1`.  Then what is sent back as the response.  Then, some other client requests `http://myserver.com/route2`.  Then what is sent back as the response.  That's the kind of description we would need to help you.  You're buried so deep in some misconception about how requests work that you haven't even described what the end result is supposed to be so we don't know what to suggest.

Comment: "get info from URL" means using the request param, and getting the into passed onto the URL. Got it, give me a minute to edit my question, thank you for your time till now!

Comment: @jfriend00 I edited the post.

Comment: In your edit, what's the problem with exactly the scheme you show?  What are you asking for help with?  You can certainly call a function and pass arguments to it from a route handler. 
What kinds of things are you expecting to do in `function_A()`?